# X supported by not all the XYZ

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

> Please note that fenced code blocks, backslashed line blocks, numbered lists that start with a number other than 1, tables, footnotes, and HTML comments are **supported by not all** the Markdown implementations.

This is from my own Markdown guide.

I try to understand whether "supported by not all" sounds good to native speakers.

The meaning that I try to convey is that those elements of syntax are supported by only 95% of Markdown implementations, whereas the remaining 5% don't support them and this might be a problem for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea would better be expressed with "...aren't supported by all the Markdown implementations."

That's the interesting thing about the negation here: it isn't exactly opposite. Instead of reducing the support from all implementations to no implementations, it reduces the support to some implementations. If you wanted to express the fact that none of the implementations support them, you would say "... aren't supported by any Markdown implementations."

Comment: Contraction isn't used elsewhere is the passage so assume they are not preferred. Recommended action is change "aren't" to "are not".